# vs code isn't copying line either up or down in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've visual studio code in my ubuntu laptop.

Below are the keyboard shortcuts -

[image: VS Code shortcuts]

When I press `ctrl + shift + alt + uparrow`, it isn't duplicating the line.

Below are my VS code info -

```
    Version: 1.36.0
    Commit: 0f3794b38477eea13fb47fbe15a42798e6129338
    Date: 2019-07-03T13:20:56.241Z
    Electron: 4.2.5
    Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
    Node.js: 10.11.0
    V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
    OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-54-generic
```

Below is my Os info -

```
    $ cat /etc/os-release 
    NAME="Ubuntu"
    VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
    ID=ubuntu
    ID_LIKE=debian
    PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
    VERSION_ID="16.04"
    HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
    SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
    BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
    VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
    UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Any idea how can I resolve this issue?